# Errors upgrading the linux kernel on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 15.04

I've had to upgrade the kernel on Ubuntu 15.04 to get better drivers for my laptop (xps 13 9343). I have followed the instruction from http://hgdev.co/installing-ubuntu-15-04-on-the-xps-13-9343-2015-a-complete-guide/

However, some modules (**i915** and **virtualbox**) dot not build during the upgrade. Here's what I get when I do `sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.1.6*.deb linux-image-4.1.6*.deb`

```
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.1.6-040106-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.1.6-040106-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/i915-3.19-3.13/3.19.1/build/make.log for more information.
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.1.6-040106-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.1.6-040106-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.26/build/make.log for more information.
```

The whole output is there http://dpaste.com/32VF8Y5

Here's the make log for the i915 module http://dpaste.com/1A9Z1DM.txt

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the Broadcom Wifi driver failed to compile (it is not compatible yet with 4.x kernel).

Simply install [bcmwl-kernel-source](https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248%2bbdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb) ([Mirror](http://hgdev.co/wp-content/uploads/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb))  deb package from the Wily repository, reboot and you are good to go.

Some error report will prompt after a reboot. Ignore them and they won't come back.

Comment: The problem is not with the bcmwl module. If you look more closely at the logs, you will see that I'm getting error for i915-3.19-3.13 (GPU) and virtualbox modules.